# VISA library on Windows XP for use with PyVisa

Tags: python, visa

I'm trying to control some instruments with a program written in Python using the PyVisa module. I installed National Instruments' VISA library as instructed on the PyVisa [page](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting.html)

Everything in Windows XP (32bit). PyVisa module is installed correctly, I think. I can load the module from python and access its components.

Now, the problem comes when I try to access the library itself. Calling `visa.ResourceManager()` should return the library path, but it returns no path at all: Python has no idea where the library is. Neither do I. I try to find it manually and add its path when calling the functions, as explained [here](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuring.html)

But since I don't know where it is, I can not do it.

That's for Windows XP. On Mac, I follow the same process and everything works out of the box. But the Mac computer has not the GPIB card I have to use so I am doomed to use the windows computer.

I would appreciate all help you might provide.

Comment: I hope you have restarted your computer after installing the NI Visa library.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the computer after installing the Visa. I've found somewhere that the library I'm looking for is "c:\windows\system32\visa32.dll". I've configured it but still the visa.ResourceManager() command shows no library at all.

Comment: see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047384/pyvisa-missing-methods/24363423#24363423
have you told pyvisa where to look with vpp?